# Increasing and bounded sequence of nested supersets converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose that $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}, (A_n \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, & $A_n \subseteq A_{n+1})$. Thus $(A_n)_n$ is an increasing and bounded sequence of nested supersets. Can one conclude that there is, in a sense, a limit to this sequence; that is $\exists A \subseteq \mathbb{R}: \lim_{n \to \infty}(A_n) = A$ in some sense? This would be like the Monotone Convergence Theorem, but for sets.

My intuition says that this seems quite plausible, but I do not even know how to formalize the notion of the limit and do not know how to look this up.

(This is just a random question which I have and is not associated with any assignment or anything like that, so I have no work to share).

Comment: You don’t need it to be bounded. You can simply take $$\lim A_n = \bigcup_{n\geq 1} A_n$$ More generally, one defines the limit of a sequence of sets if $\liminf A_n=\limsup A_n$ where $$\limsup A_n = \bigcap_{n\geq 1}\bigcup_{k\geq n}A_k$$ and $$\liminf A_n=\bigcup_{n\geq 1}\bigcap_{k\geq n} A_k$$ In words, $\limsup A_n$ are the points which occur infinitely often, and $\liminf A_n$ the points which occur all but finitely often.

Comment: So, you are saying that any nested sequence of sets with limsup and liminf, as you defined them, being mutually equal to have a limit? With or without the boundedness, can we conclude anything about the set which contains this limit? For example, with my boundedness condition, can I conclude that the limit is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes, as long as your sequence is increasing (resp. decreasing), the limit always exists and is given by the union (resp. intersection).